# Refresh button in glTF

Tags: three.js

Is there an easy way to add a refresh button in glTF?
Or rather reload textures etc?

The way ***not*** to do it, would be:

```
            if (gui.reset > 0)
            {
                console.log("RESET!");
                gui.reset = 0;
                init();
            }
```

The idea being, not a reset button as such, but a button that changes the texture set,lighting environment,shaders etc. on the same model.

Or is it more practical to load both sets of data and switch between the two?

Comment: Just scene.traverse( (node) and if node.isMesh then do stuff to it. node.material.map = someOtherTexture... etc.

Comment: This isn't really a glTF question, so I'll remove that tag. The way to change a model — any model — in three.js is to use the three.js API. Modify materials to change appearance, modify lights to change lighting. You may need to ask a more specific question to get much more help, sorry!